# Suddenly Images not loading in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Hi I have a wordpress site , and it worked well till yesterday.
http://nextinweb.com/
Now the images are not loading in page , if I click on the space of images , and open in new tab , it will show.

I haven't made any changes for the last 3 days.
no new plugins or updates.
I upload images using the word press built in image uploader.

All plugins are updated , wordpress is the latest version.
Running in Siteground server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on your style.css line 23882, "entry-thumb" class, images opacity is 0

```
body.td-animation-stack-type0 .td-animation-stack .entry-thumb, body.td-animation-stack-type0 .post img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: the theme has the same style . I mean the original theme file has the same line in it !!! I tried changing it , but didnt help....

Comment: YES!! I did it and it worked. Thanks  a lot. (tried to edit my old comment , but cant save it !! )The original css (backup css) has the same lines!!! strange !!

Comment: You got -> Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#].
I think there some issue with the update or jquery 1.12.x. 
try put back that opacity to 0 and upgrade your jQuery version to v2.0 or maybe newest version if your theme supported.

Comment: that sytax error was sue to an edit in a config file !! I have reversed it after seeing the error. I have also put back the default is with opacity 0 , now the problem seems to be fixed... I dont know what really happened.